# 'Pong' ball not resetting

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging

I'm writing my own Pong game in C# and I'm having some issues with my ball not resetting correctly. I've spent a good hour or two debugging the code but I can't figure it out.

Basically what's supposed to happen is that when the ball is detected to leave the bounds of the window then the `Center()` method is going to get called and `Center()` then resets the ball `Point` by accessing the backing field directly. Now this works, I've verified that it does what it's supposed to by stepping through the code.

Now the weird that happens is that after `Center()` gets called the ball position reverts back to what it used to be pre-centering. Now the weird thing is that, this reset happens before the `set` accessor of the `Point` property is even called. And I'm 100% sure that I'm not accesing the backing field directly in any other place than `Center()` so I can't figure it out.. Here's the code

```
namespace Pong
{
    internal enum CollisionType
    {
        Paddle, Boundary
    }

    class Ball
    {
        private readonly IGameView view;
        private readonly IGameController controller;
        private int velocity = 10;
        private double angle;
        private event CollisionHandler Collision;
        private Point _point;
        public Point Point
        {
            get { return _point; }
            set
            {   // If UpdatePosition() tries to move the ball beyond the boundaries in one tick move the ball to the boundaries
                if(value.Y > view.Boundaries.Height || value.Y < 0) 
                {
                    _point = new Point(value.X, view.Boundaries.Height);
                    Collision(CollisionType.Boundary); // Also raise the collision event
                }

                //If the ball is going to pass the X boundaries of the map then a player should score and the ball should reset
                if (value.X > view.Boundaries.Width || value.X < 0)
                {
                    if (angle > 90) // If the angle of the ball of the ball is above 90 degrees then the left paddle was the shooter
                    {               // So he should score
                        var scoringPlayer = Array.Find(controller.Players, player => player.Paddle.Orientation.Equals(Orientation.Left));
                        controller.PlayerScore(scoringPlayer);
                        Center(scoringPlayer);
                    } 
                    else // If not, then it's the right paddle
                    {
                        var scoringPlayer = Array.Find(controller.Players, player => player.Paddle.Orientation.Equals(Orientation.Right));
                        controller.PlayerScore(scoringPlayer);
                        Center(scoringPlayer);
                    }
                }

                // If the ball will collide with a player paddle then raise collision event
                if (controller.Players.Any(player => player.Paddle.Position.Equals(value)))
                {
                    Collision(CollisionType.Paddle);
                    _point = value;
                }

                _point = value;
            }
        }

        public Ball(IGameView view, IGameController controller)
        {
            this.view = view;
            this.controller = controller;                                       
        }

        public void Center(Player server)
        {
            //Center the ball, acccess the backing field directly to avoid all the conditional logic in the property
            _point = new Point(view.Boundaries.Width / 2, view.Boundaries.Height / 2);    

            //The ball will start moving from the center Point towards one of the different sides
            /*TODO: Apparently the ball moves sideways down towards one of the player paddles, so we must implement more complex
              logic to calculate the starting angle of the ball */
            angle = (server.Paddle.Orientation.Equals(Orientation.Left)) ? 0 : 180;
        }

        public void UpdatePosition()
        {
            //Called to update ball position based on velocity and angle of ball

            //For now let's just implement a very primitive movement algorithm
            if (angle < 90)
            {
                Point = new Point(Point.X + velocity, Point.Y);
            } 
            else
            {
                Point = new Point(Point.X - velocity, Point.Y);
            }
        }
    }   
    //TODO: Add collision detection through BallCollision Event and implement BallCollisionHandler(CollisionType as Object args)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `_point = value` immediately after you call `Center` - you need to ensure that your backing field isn't updated after you set it during `Center`

```
public Point Point
{
    get { return _point; }
    set
    {   // If UpdatePosition() tries to move the ball beyond the boundaries in one tick move the ball to the boundaries
        if(value.Y > view.Boundaries.Height || value.Y < 0) 
        {
            _point = new Point(value.X, view.Boundaries.Height);
            Collision(CollisionType.Boundary); // Also raise the collision event
        }

        //If the ball is going to pass the X boundaries of the map then a player should score and the ball should reset
        if (value.X > view.Boundaries.Width || value.X < 0)
        {
            if (angle > 90) // If the angle of the ball of the ball is above 90 degrees then the left paddle was the shooter
            {               // So he should score
                var scoringPlayer = Array.Find(controller.Players, player => player.Paddle.Orientation.Equals(Orientation.Left));
                controller.PlayerScore(scoringPlayer);
                Center(scoringPlayer);
            } 
            else // If not, then it's the right paddle
            {
                var scoringPlayer = Array.Find(controller.Players, player => player.Paddle.Orientation.Equals(Orientation.Right));
                controller.PlayerScore(scoringPlayer);
                Center(scoringPlayer);
            }
        }

        // If the ball will collide with a player paddle then raise collision event
        if (controller.Players.Any(player => player.Paddle.Position.Equals(value)))
        {
            Collision(CollisionType.Paddle);
            _point = value;
        }

        _point = value; // <--- This always gets set - even after you call Center above
    }
}
```

Edit:

As Sayse pointed out whilst this is the issue you are getting, it might be useful to move this logic into an 'update' part of the code - this logic seems like it should be part of the `IGameController` implementation or a `IBallController` maybe; either that or put an `Update` method into your `Ball` class which is called by the game controller when it wants to update all game objects

Property setters ideally shouldn't be side-effecting

Comment: Your answer although correct, is still encouraging bad code with property setter misuse

Comment: I agree, setters should be deterministic - I'd probably put this stuff into an 'update' loop rather than in a setter, but I just answered the question :)

Comment: Yeah, that worked! Also regarding properties, I didn't know that, but I guess it makes sense that they should only be used for validation and stuff. I'm reworking the code by implementing a `BallController` class.